# Why are my microgels not centrifuging (sticking to tube)?

Tags: polymers

I have created a hydrogel water in oil emulsion using a microfluidic flow focusing device. I have been able to collect the microgels/particles from the device and then pipette/manipulate them. When I try to centrifuge them to wash them they seem to aggregate and stick to the tube walls instead of collect at the bottom of the tube. What could be causing this and how do I fix it? Below are some relevant details.

Water phase: 2 wt% Norbornene-modified hyaluronic acid, DTT (crosslinker), .1% Irgacure I2959 (photoinitiator)

Oil phase: Light mineral oil with 2% span 80 (surfactant), .1% Irgacure I2959 (photoinitiator)

[image: Image of microgel aggregation/sticking]

Comment: Have you tried to change the material of the centrifuge tubes? It looks like you are using PP or PET; try PTFE instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion, I really appreciate it. I am using polypropylene tubes. I tried looking for PTFE but I don't see any in a clear/conical form. I ended up adding acetone and that seemed to solve the problem. I'm not sure exactly why though. I read about it being able to pull the surfactant out of the oil phase due to polarity, does that seem correct?